# Syntax error when importing MySQL function

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I get a #1064 syntax error on the beginning of line 5's if clause when trying to run the following code in PhpMyAdmin:

```
DELIMITER ;
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` FUNCTION `ANREDE`(geschlecht enum('m','w'), vorname VARCHAR(255), nachname VARCHAR(255)) RETURNS varchar(1023) CHARSET latin1
    DETERMINISTIC
BEGIN
     IF geschlecht = 'm' THEN RETURN CONCAT_WS('',CONCAT_WS(' ','Sehr geehrter Herr',vorname,nachname),',');
     ELSE RETURN CONCAT_WS('',CONCAT_WS(' ','Sehr geehrte Frau',vorname,nachname),',');
END IF;
    END
```

It seems to me the if clause is correct - what could cause such an error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either use `DELIMITER` or you can rewrite your function to make it one-statement function like so

```
CREATE FUNCTION `ANREDE`
(
  geschlecht enum('m','w'), 
  vorname VARCHAR(255), 
  nachname VARCHAR(255)
) 
RETURNS VARCHAR(1023) CHARSET latin1
DETERMINISTIC
  RETURN CONCAT
          (CONCAT_WS(' ', 
                     IF(geschlecht = 'm', 
                        'Sehr geehrter Herr', 
                        'Sehr geehrte Frau'), 
                     vorname, 
                     nachname),
          ',');
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/aafff)** demo.

Answer (score 0):

You need to change your delimiter. Currently, `;` is your delimiter, and the parser interprets your `;`, at the end of line 5, as the end of your function creation statement.

Try this:

```
DELIMITER // -- change the delimiter

CREATE ...
BEGIN
    IF ... ; -- this is not the end of the statement
    ...
END
// -- end of statement

DELIMITER ; -- useless if you issue this in PhpMyAdmin, but a good practice nevertheless
```